# Login CakePHP 2.0 não funciona

Tags: php, cakephp, auth

Já tinha feito com sucesso o sistema de login com a tabela e os campos que vêm por defeito no cakephp, resolvi mudar a tabela e os campos para login e agora não efetua login.

Ficheiro Registos/login.ctp:

```
      <div class="large-4 columns" style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 0px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="users form">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->create('Registos'); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('email');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
            ?>
        </fieldset>
           <?php  
                 echo $this->Form->submit(
                 'Login', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
            </div>
</div>
```

Ficheiro AppController:

```
    class AppController extends Controller {


     public $components = array(
      'Session',
      'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'Registo',
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
            )
        )
    ),
    'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'registos', 'action' => 'login'), 
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'anuncios', 'action' => 'index')
     )
    );

 function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->allow();
}

 }
```

Action Login:

```
    public function login() {

       if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
       } else {
        //$this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
      }
    }
```

A minha tabela na base de dados chama-se utilizadores e tem o email e a password.

Ele chega a action login com os valores do email e da password certos, mas não faz o login, suspeito que não está a verificar na tabela certa, porém não percebo porque.

Comment: Você indicou no model o nome da tabela?

Comment: Acho que você está chamando o model errado na sua view

Answer (score 1):

Percebi 2 erros no seu código

1 - Se a tabela que guarda seus usuários chama-se "utilizadores" você deve criar o *Form* para o *Model* "Utilizador":

2 - Se a tabela que você deseja for realmente "registros" então o *Form*  deve ser criado usando o nome do model no singular "Registro"

Sendo assim, onde tem

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Registos'); ?>
```

dferia ser

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Utilizador'); ?>
```

ou

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Registro'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema com a versão 2.4.5, tive que deixar a tabela como USER mesmo que é o padrão do CAKE.
Segue o meu código:

**AppController**

```
class AppController extends Controller {


public $components = array(
    'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'painels', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
        )
    )

    ));


public function beforeFilter() {
       $this->Auth->allow();
    }

public function isAuthorized($user) {   
    return true;
}
```

}

**UsersController**

```
  public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('login', 'add');

}

public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'home';

    //if already logged-in, redirect
    if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')) {
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'painels', 'action' => 'index'));
    }


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login ou senha invalida.'));
        }
    }
}

public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

**Model User**

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }

    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']);
    }


    // fallback to our parent
    return parent::beforeSave($options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quanto ao problema de usar outros campos ao invés dos padrões do cake, eu consegui resolver isso configurando diretamente no beforeFilter do AppController:

```
          $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            AuthComponent::ALL => array(
                'userModel' => 'Usuario',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'senha'
                    ),
                'scope' => array(
                    'User.status' => 1,
                    ),
                ),
            'Form',
        );
```